# Importing data from Excel to SQL Server database using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: sql-server, excel, oledb

I'm developing an application where I need to import data from Excel to an MS SQL Server database.
I've installed [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)  on the MS SQL Server machine as well as on my machine

Configured the MS SQL Server like this:

```
USE [master]
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OverRide
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OverRide
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO
```

In my application I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=PathToMyExcelDoc', [Devices$])
```

When the application and SQL Server are on the same machine, it works fine, but when I'm running the application on my machine and try to import data from Excel to a remote SQL Server, I get the following error:

```
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing same problem, I resolved it by first saving the excel to server and then  passing that path in OPENROWSET.

Comment: So you mean: when I browse for an Excel file, then I must first upload it to the server where the SQL Server is, then perform importing data.
If yes, how do I upload a file to a remote server in this case? I'm working on a WPF application (C#).

Comment: yes ofcourse.....

actually i am still learning WPF with this part i might not be very helpful...

Comment: Thank you, but what about the second part of my comment (how to upload file?).

Comment: This [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8b62868e-dced-471b-80cb-ad2b616313ff) may help you